# Roblox Run Script From String in variable

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a ss script that runs by turning the text inside the TextBox into a variable and running the variable as a script, how do I do this?
I tried to use loadstring but it didn't work, what do I do?

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    local script = script.Parent.Parent.TextBox.Text
    loadstring(script)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

If no errors occur loadstring returns the loaded chunk as a function.

You failed to call that function.

```
assert(loadstring(script))()
```

Please read the Lua manual. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring

Comment: Ah I forgot to add that thanks!